# Simulink Capacitor doesn't load in simulation

Tags: capacitor, matlab

I have a capacitor connected to a Voltage source in Simulink and it doesn't load with Voltage. The voltage remains constant (3V).

What did I do wrong ?

The Simulation says the voltage across capacitor of 1 Farad is constant and equal with Voltage source ....
[image: Model]
[image: Logging]

**update:**

I added a Current source of 1A instead of Voltage source and now it works better.

But I am not sure the voltage graphs are correct. 
The voltage at t shall be vc = V[0] + t*I; where V[0] is 0

[image: WIth current source]

Comment: What voltage do you expect across the capacitor?

Comment: I used 3 Volts for the voltage source

Comment: So there should be 3V across the capacitor. There's no resistance in the circuit, hence the time constant is \$\tau=0s\$, i.e. the charging current is an impulse and the capacitor charges to 3V instantaneously. These signals can all be seen in the graphs.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you were expecting an exponential curve but are surprised why you are seeing just 3V?

Creating an exact SIMSCAPE (not simulink for correctness) as you have I generate the same & expected waveforms

[image]

What you appear to have missed is the VERY large current spike and the fast increase in voltage right at the start.

[image]

This is exactly the same result but the x-axis (time) rescaled to 1e-05 seconds.

Here you see three things

1. The current is large and rapidly decays, with a default of \$1\mu\Omega\$ for a simscape resistance, this is what a t=0 current would look like (from an ideal source)
2. The voltage of the source. This is a quirk/"recording method" of SIMSCAPE where it then shows you the voltage applied to an element & in this case the element consists of an R and a C 
   [image]
3. The voltage of the capacitance. This you see has an expected RC curve based upon a C of 1F and an R of \$1\mu\Omega\$

Comment: i have no resistor conected to the voltage source .... Only a Capacitor

Comment: that is true, but what value exists for the series resistance of the capacitance within simscape?  it cannot be zero as it throws an algebraic error

Comment: its 1e-6.... indeed if i zoom at start in increments of 1*10^-4 i see the slope

Comment: Anyway i found myself the answer .... I need to add Current source ... Not voltage Source. Now the slope is increasing every 1 second like i shown. PS: you seem to have crappy old version of MATLAB O_O

Comment: if that is what you are wanting to see... since you are modeling i = Cdv/dt   a constant i and a constant C will create a linear ramp in voltage. Equally a constant V and a constant C will create an exponential i... really comes downto what you are trying to model

Comment: Exactly. You just answered yourself. Nothing more to add from my side ;)

Comment: Omg , i had selected as solver Backward Euler. If i uncheck it the slope becomes more like a curve O-o .. WTF. ALso VERY STRANGE. If i select a voltage source the simulation runs very slowly , but if i select a Current source is instant, independent of solver config

Answer (score -1):

Try putting a 1 ohm resistor between the voltage source and the capacitor, then plotting the voltage across the capacitor.

At the moment all the interesting action occurs in the first timestep.

Comment: Ok when i get home i will try it

Comment: It doesnt do anything....its the same  if i add an 1 Ohm resistor

Comment: You are not doing it right then - it should take 1 second for the capacitor to charge up to 63%, about 5 seconds to charge up to within 1% of the voltage source. Are you doing the start-up correctly? You don't want Simulink to wait for a stable state before it starts collecting data, you need to see the startup.

Comment: The equation is vc = V[0] + t*I; where V[0] is 0, i checked it and the graph follows it , at t=1 sec the Current is 1 (I=1 ampere)